# Putting commas around "in his opinion"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is there any exception to using commas around interruptions such as 'in his opinion'? Specifically, I have the following situation, wherein I'd be left with a closed-off 'that':

> He chose three projects, A, B and C, that, in his opinion, corresponded to outstanding, good and poor executions of the method.

Would it be admissible to drop the commas? Should it stay as is? Or is there a new way altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just worried about comma overload, you can rephrase the statement as

> He chose three projects, A, B and C, that he thought corresponded to outstanding, good and poor executions of the method.

Since I usually work with serial commas, I would be inclined to break out the designations A, B, and C with em dashes:

> He chose three projects—A, B, and C—that he thought corresponded to outstanding, good, and poor executions of the method.

But to get back to your original question, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with having a *that* with commas on both sides of it, as in

> He chose three projects, A, B and C, that, in his opinion, corresponded to outstanding, good and poor executions of the method.

Comment: Thanks! For both the answer and rephrasing. I'll be using your first proposition, as I'm wary of using em dashes in this particular text.